# Error in print function "End of statement expected"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This is an answer for a question in hacker rank Python challenges.
I am using Python 3.0. It works fine on their web site, but it shows an error in my PyCharm IDE as:

> "End of statement expected".

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
print(*range(1, n+1), sep='', end='')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be Your PyCharm IDE using Python 2.x. In Python 2.x this line `print(*range(1, n+1), sep='', end='')` is not correct syntactically.

This code will work for you in Python 2.x

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    list=range(1, n+1)
    print ''.join(map(str, list))
```